# Azure Blob Storage Videos

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm creating a xamarin forms app with Azure and I want it to use large images and videos.

I already know how to make it work with images (Blob Storage and Azure functions) but I have no idea with videos.
I mean if an user upload a 4K video into my blob storage, it has to be compressed (probably before being send to the blob storage). I don't know where to start - I've seen Blob storage encoding, Media services and CDN but I don't know if it's the right path. Can someone enlighten me on that matter?

Comment: You can still use Azure Functions with something like ffmpeg.exe for encoding in an App Service Plan (dedicated SKU). This will avoid any execution time limits. Pick a good size instance, encoding from 4k sources is not a light workload.

Comment: I'll take a look at it, thanks !